# Operation on String - Substrings: Get Positions and Count

Tags: php

I have a problem with operations on a string in PHP, I have one string like this:

```
$words = "Ala ma kota a kot ma ale";
```

How do I get the number of appearances of `al` in this long string `$words`? Additionally, I need the index of the beginning of all appearances of `al`.

```
$count = substr_count($words, 'al');
```

I tried it with the `substr_count()`, but it only returned the count. I need the index of the appearance as well.

**EDIT** Adding expected output:

```
number of al: 2, at index: 0, at index: 22
```

Comment: could you add the expected outcome to your question, it is not entirely clear...

Comment: number of `al`: 2, at index: 0, at index: 22

Answer (score 2):

You could build a loop that continuously searches the array, until you run out of count, probably. Or you could wing it and make a loop that continuously does `strpos()` and count it in the end. Note that you need to somehow make sure you're not checking the same position over and over, that's what the `$position++` is there in this piece of code.

Here, this will output exactly what you asked for in the comment, with the correct position that is. (I didn't see the comment before)

```
$position = 0;
$words = strtolower("Ala ma kota a kot ma ale");
$needle = 'al';

$positions = [];

do {
    
    $position = strpos($words, $needle, $position);
    
    if ($position !== false) {
        array_push($positions, $position);
        $position++;
    }
} while ($position);

echo 'number of al: '.count($positions);

foreach ($positions as $position) {
    echo ', at index: '.$position;
}
```

Output:

```
number of al: 2, at index: 0, at index: 21
```

Edit: As noted by [eis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365237/eis), this could be simplified down to

```
<?php
$position = 0;
$words = strtolower("Ala ma kota a kot ma alet ma ale");
$needle = 'al';

$positions = [];

$position = -1;
while (($position = strpos($words, $needle, $position + 1)) !== false) {
    array_push($positions, $position);
}

echo 'number of al: ' . count($positions);

foreach ($positions as $position) {
    echo ', at index: ' . $position;
}
```

Edit: As [Markus AO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4630325/markus-ao) said, you might want to base your position movement (`position++;`) on the length of the needle. I think that depends on the way you wish to match.
a) If you want to match all appearances (aba → abababa = 3 ... match may occur within the previous match,) keep it this way.
b) If you want to match all 'full' appearances (aba → abababa = 2,) increment the position by the needle's length.

Comment: In `if ($position >= 0 && $position !== false)`, would `$position !== false` in itself be sufficient, since `strpos` only returns `false` or an integer? Also, what's the purpose of `$position++`, is it simply to avoid `while` breaking if position is `0`? If so, `while($position !== false)` would seem to do the trick?

Comment: @MarkusAO maybe even just `while(($position = strpos($words, $needle, $position)) !== false) { array_push($positions, $position); }`

Comment: @eis unless I'm missing something, in this context, your loop would result in a memory allocation error. (tested it to check that theory)

Comment: @MarkusAO you're right, I'll remove the redundant piece, I also have a feeling that you'd run into a memory issue as well with the while. You'd end up checking the same position over and over, resulting in an endless loop, no? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Morgosus yeah, additional +1 is needed. So `$position = -1; while(($position = strpos($words, $needle, $position+1)) !== false) { array_push($positions, $position); }`

Comment: Right, you are incrementing the `strpos` offset. In that case, might be an idea to `$needle_length = strlen($needle)` outside the loop, and then advance the position by needle length? Otherwise, we'd be starting the matching one character into the previous match. :)

Comment: @MarkusAO see, the issue with that is, what if the match is there... let's say it's 'aba' and we want to check within ababababa, that'd give us 2, while in fact  there are 4... if I'm counting correctly, I think this particular part would differ depending on what exactly we're looking for, but I'm assuming that since the question was about matching appearances of a string (and it's valid to match al in ale), I'll just make sure we're not checking the same place twice :D PS I think we're overthinking the question lol (but I incorporated this into the answer anyways)

Comment: Haha yes this may well be beyond what OP needs. (Unsure what the actual use case/outcome of this matching is!) In any case, a fair exercise in addressing the issue of substring position matching in general. Kudos for the many iterations that went into enhancing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is easily accomplished with [`preg_match_all()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) using `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag:

```
$words = "Ala ma kota a kot ma ale. All in Valhalla shall recall the fall.";

preg_match_all('~(al)~i', $words, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

See a live demo at https://3v4l.org/Frsa5. We have the `i` modifier for case-insensitive matching. If you want case-sensitive matching, remove it. If you want only `al`s at the start of words, use `\bal` (`\b` = word boundary). The result is an array with matches and offsets, as follows:

```
Array [
  [0] => [
      [0] => Al
      [1] => 0
    ]
  [1] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 21
    ]
  [2] => [
      [0] => Al
      [1] => 26
    ]
  [3] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 34
    ]
  [4] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 37
    ]
  [5] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 44
    ]
  [6] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 51
    ]
  [7] => [
      [0] => al
      [1] => 60
    ]
]
```

*Edit:* Since there's nothing else being matched, you don't really need the `(al)` capture group. You can also just remove the brackets, match `~al~i`, and get the results in `$matches[0]` (containing full pattern matches). I've left it as is with the capture group in place, in case you may want to use more complex matching rules in the future (& being lazy to update the demo).